# Android: Image not updating on ImageView however its updated daily on URL(source.unsplash.com/daily)

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm loading an image to my app using Glide from https://source.unsplash.com/daily?nature
It is a free to use image platform and the link above updates images daily.

However, Glide is showing the old cached image, even if the image has been updated on the site.

Code used :

```
Glide.with(this)
             .load("https://source.unsplash.com/daily?nature")
             .into(imageView);
```

**Glide Version: 4.0.0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void loadImageWithGlide(Context theCtx, ImageView theImageView, String theUrl) {
        // skipMemoryCache true, because it load the same image from cache when URL not change.
        Glide.with(theCtx)
                .load(theUrl)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .fitCenter()
                .into(theImageView);

        // use below lines, to enable memory cache. so that image does not load again ones loaded
        //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        //.skipMemoryCache(false)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
Glide.with(this)
        .load("https://source.unsplash.com/daily?nature")
        .signature(new StringSignature(yourVersionMetadata))
        .into(imageView);
```

hope it'll solve your problem. For more info see [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Caching-and-Cache-Invalidation).

Answer (score 0):

If your URL same and catch is true in glid then it load image from catch which you have chosen the first day, And I know you want to load image from only one URL

**Solution**

Just do one thing first one, Put one condition if your image loading call first time in the day then catch memory and then after load your image.

```
if(isTHisyourFirstDay){
    Glide.get(getApplicationContext()).clearMemory();
}
Glide.with(this)
    .load("https://source.unsplash.com/daily?nature")
    .into(imageView);
```